# oracle- JOIN 2 tables with 2 ID's in common

Tags: oracle

table "team1" :

```
id      country
1        India
2        Pakistan
3        srilanka
4        England
```

table "team2" :

```
id    name       name2
1      2          4
2      1          3
```

i have to combine two tables 
another table when retrieve the data that time in place of 2 , 4 Pakistan,England

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far and what issue you are facing?

Comment: What is the result you want?

Comment: <option>India</option><option>Pakistan</option><option>srilanka</option><option>England</option>  retrived from the database.now select any two country's will stored in database like team2 ,then select any one particular country ,automatically second one show in the second text box ,this is only in jsp using drop down list.i think now my requirement is clear right?

Answer (score 0):

It is about the self join of `team1` table (lines #15 and 16):

```
SQL> with
  2  team1 (id, country) as
  3    (select 1, 'India'     from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'Pakistan'  from dual union all
  5     select 3, 'Sri Lanka' from dual union all
  6     select 4, 'England'   from dual
  7    ),
  8  team2 (id, name, name2) as
  9    (select 1, 2, 4 from dual union all
 10     select 2, 1, 3 from dual
 11    )
 12  select b.id,
 13         t1.country,
 14         t2.country
 15  from team2 b join team1 t1 on t1.id = b.name
 16               join team1 t2 on t2.id = b.name2
 17  order by b.id;

        ID COUNTRY   COUNTRY
---------- --------- ---------
         1 Pakistan  England
         2 India     Sri Lanka

SQL>
```

Comment: how to write this query  in jsp .

Comment: I don't speak jsp, sorry. If it helps, as you already have those tables, code you *really* need is from lines #12 to line #16.

Answer (score 0):

Just showing another way of writing the same query with aggregate functions and grouping.

```
with
   team1 (id, country) as
     (select 1, 'India'     from dual union all
      select 2, 'Pakistan'  from dual union all
      select 3, 'Sri Lanka' from dual union all
      select 4, 'England'   from dual
     ),
   team2 (id, name, name2) as
     (select 1, 2, 4 from dual union all
      select 2, 1, 3 from dual
     )
SELECT
    T2.ID,
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN T2.NAME = T1.ID THEN T1.COUNTRY
    END) AS TEAM1,
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN T2.NAME2 = T1.ID THEN T1.COUNTRY
    END) AS TEAM2
FROM
    TEAM2 T2
    JOIN TEAM1 T1 ON T1.ID IN (
        T2.NAME,
        T2.NAME2
    )
GROUP BY
    T2.ID
ORDER BY
    T2.ID;
```

Output:

```
        ID TEAM1     TEAM2    
---------- --------- ---------
         1 Pakistan  England  
         2 India     Sri Lanka
```

Cheers!!

Comment: If that answer solved your question then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so that your question is marked as resolved.